# XSLT - Group by preceding element and apply templates

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all i use Apache FOP version 2.8 with saxonHE12 available.

I have the following xml input:

```xml
<viewport>
    <id name="123"/>
    <font family="sans-serif" style="normal" weight="400" variant="normal" size="10000" color="#000000"/>
    <text>foo 1</text>
    <id name="#321"/>
    <text>foo 2</text>
    <id name="123"/>
    <text>foo 3</text>
    <text>foo 4</text>
    <text>foo 5</text>
    <id name="456"/>
    <text>foo 6</text>
    <text>foo 7</text>
    <id name="789"/>
    <text>foo 8</text>
    <text>foo 9</text>
    <text>foo 10</text>
</viewport>
```

Every `text` element that has a preceding `id` element WITHOUT a leading `#` belongs to a text-section identified by that id.
e.g

- `foo 1-5` belong to text-section `123`
- `foo 6-7` belong to text-section `456`
- `foo 8-10` belong to text-section `789`

The special thing is that `foo 2` belongs to `123` BUT also this text is also identified by the id `#321`

So what i want is to turn this into `HTML`

The desired output looks like:

```html
<div id="123">
    <span>foo 1</span>
    <span id="#321">foo 2</span>
    <span>foo 3</span>
    <span>foo 4</span>
    <span>foo 5</span>
<div/>
<div id="456">
    <span>foo 6</span>
    <span>foo 7</span>
<div/>
<div id="789">
    <span>foo 8</span>
    <span>foo 9</span>
    <span>foo 10</span>
<div/>
```

---

I already tried writing my XSLT templates like so:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:template match="*|/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
  </xsl:template>
              
  <xsl:template match="viewport">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="not(fn:starts-with(@name, '#'))">
      <div class="element-container" id="{$name}">
        <!-- all following text elements that have an id element with the current id -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following::text[preceding::id[not(fn:starts-with($name, '#'))]/@name = $name]"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:variable name="special-id"><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::id[1][fn:starts-with(@name, '#')]/@name"/></xsl:variable>
        <span>
          <xsl:if test="$special-id != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$special-id"/></xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </span>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that the problem is that the text template is called multiple times but I just can't get it to produce the desired output.
I already tried with viewport `<xsl:apply-templates select="./* except text"/>` so that the texttemplate is not called from the viewport but only from the id template but then I still have the problem with the double id elements...

- [Test case with  select="./*"](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22*%7C%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22.%2F*%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22viewport%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22.%2F*%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22id%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22name%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%40name%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22not%28fn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C%20%27%23%27%29%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22element-container%22%20id%3D%22%7B%24name%7D%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20all%20following%20text%20elements%20that%20have%20an%20id%20element%20with%20the%20current%20id%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22following%3A%3Atext%5Bpreceding%3A%3Aid%5Bnot%28fn%3Astarts-with%28%24name%2C%20%27%23%27%29%29%5D%2F%40name%20%3D%20%24name%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22text%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22special-id%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22preceding-sibling%3A%3Aid%5B1%5D%5Bfn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C%20%27%23%27%29%5D%2F%40name%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22%24special-id%20%21%3D%20%27%27%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22id%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24special-id%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Aattribute%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22text%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Cviewport%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22123%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cfont%20family%3D%22sans-serif%22%20style%3D%22normal%22%20weight%3D%22400%22%20variant%3D%22normal%22%20size%3D%2210000%22%20color%3D%22%23000000%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%201%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22%23321%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%202%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22123%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%203%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%204%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%205%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22456%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%206%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%207%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22789%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%208%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%209%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%2010%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fviewport%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML)
- [Test case with select="./* except text"](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%221.0%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22*%7C%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22.%2F*%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22viewport%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22.%2F*%20except%20text%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22id%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22name%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%40name%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22not%28fn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C%20%27%23%27%29%29%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22element-container%22%20id%3D%22%7B%24name%7D%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20all%20following%20text%20elements%20that%20have%20an%20id%20element%20with%20the%20current%20id%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22following%3A%3Atext%5Bpreceding%3A%3Aid%5Bnot%28fn%3Astarts-with%28%24name%2C%20%27%23%27%29%29%5D%2F%40name%20%3D%20%24name%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22text%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22special-id%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22preceding-sibling%3A%3Aid%5B1%5D%5Bfn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C%20%27%23%27%29%5D%2F%40name%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22%24special-id%20%21%3D%20%27%27%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22id%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24special-id%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Aattribute%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22text%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Cviewport%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22123%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cfont%20family%3D%22sans-serif%22%20style%3D%22normal%22%20weight%3D%22400%22%20variant%3D%22normal%22%20size%3D%2210000%22%20color%3D%22%23000000%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%201%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22%23321%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%202%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22123%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%203%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%204%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%205%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22456%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%206%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%207%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid%20name%3D%22789%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%208%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%209%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo%2010%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fviewport%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML)

I would prefer to be able to do without the id template completely but I just can't find a solution for this...

---

**EDIT:**

I found a leightweight solution but it requires that each text element has an id.
This is unfortunately not the case in practice

**EDIT EDIT:**

Found the final solution that im fine with now.

- [Solution 1](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+version%3D%221.0%22%0A++++++++++++++++xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A++++++++++++++++xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0A%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22*%7C%2F%22%3E%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22.%2F*%22%2F%3E%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A++++++++++++++%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22viewport%22%3E%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group+select%3D%22.%2F*%22+group-by%3D%22if%28preceding-sibling%3A%3Aid%5Bnot%28fn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C+%27%23%27%29%29%5D%5B1%5D%2F%40name+%21%3D+%27%27%29+then+%28preceding-sibling%3A%3Aid%5Bnot%28fn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C+%27%23%27%29%29%5D%5B1%5D%2F%40name%29+else+%27%27%22%3E%0A++++++%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Awhen+test%3D%22current-grouping-key%28%29+%21%3D+%27%27%22%3E%0A++++++++++%3Cdiv+class%3D%22report-element%22+id%3D%22%7Bcurrent-grouping-key%28%29%7D%22%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A++++++++++%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A++++++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A++++++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A++++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A++%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22text%22%3E%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22special-id%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22preceding-sibling%3A%3Aid%5B1%5D%5Bfn%3Astarts-with%28%40name%2C+%27%23%27%29%5D%2F%40name%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A++++++++%3Cspan%3E%0A++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Aif+test%3D%22%24special-id+%21%3D+%27%27%22%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Aattribute+name%3D%22id%22%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22%24special-id%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Aattribute%3E%0A++++++++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0A++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22text%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A++++++++%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Cviewport%3E%0D%0A++%3Ctext%3EThis+is+a+text+without+id%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid+name%3D%22123%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cfont+family%3D%22sans-serif%22+style%3D%22normal%22+weight%3D%22400%22+variant%3D%22normal%22+size%3D%2210000%22+color%3D%22%23000000%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+1%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid+name%3D%22%23321%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+2%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid+name%3D%22123%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+3%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+4%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+5%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid+name%3D%22456%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+6%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+7%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cid+name%3D%22789%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+8%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+9%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ctext%3Efoo+10%3C%2Ftext%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fviewport%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relation between the `<id name="#321"/>` and the `<text>foo 2</text>`? Does the `<id name="#321"/>` define the id of the immediately following, first sibling element?

Comment: Is `<id name="123"/>` really two times in the input? If so, what would happen if there were another `id name="xxx"` in between the two `<id name="123"/>`?

Comment: Hi Martin, nice to have you here again :) 
An `id` element generally defines all following siblings until it gets overwritten by another `id` element.

But ids with a leading `#` are not really overwriting. Its just an additional info that this specific text has a special id...

Comment: And yes the `<id name="123"/>` is two times in the input. The second id defines how many elements are affected by the `special-id` (#321)

Answer (score 0):

I have not fully grasped the requirements and I doubt the single examples allows us to understand all possible variations of the input and the wanted output but it sounds as if you want to use `for-each-group group-starting-with` in some way so here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="viewport">
    <xsl:variable name="div-groups" as="element(div)*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="id[not(starts-with(@name, '#'))]">
        <div id="{@name}">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-starting-with="id[starts-with(@name, '#')]">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="self::id[starts-with(@name, '#')]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())">
                  <xsl:with-param name="idref" select="@name" tunnel="yes"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$div-groups" group-by="@id">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:sequence select="@id, current-group()/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>

  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="font"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:param name="idref" tunnel="yes" select="()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$idref and position() eq 1">
        <span id="{$idref}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <span>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (when using `method="xml"` as HTML method doesn't indent the span elements):

```
<div id="123">
   <span>foo 1</span>
   <span id="#321">foo 2</span>
   <span>foo 3</span>
   <span>foo 4</span>
   <span>foo 5</span>
</div>
<div id="456">
   <span>foo 6</span>
   <span>foo 7</span>
</div>
<div id="789">
   <span>foo 8</span>
   <span>foo 9</span>
   <span>foo 10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the example input i gave is just the simplified version... there can be also nested viewports and groups etc. 
Thats why i was looking for a solution with only touching the text template...

Comment: Hey Martin i found another solution also by editing the viewport template but its more leightweight... I edited my question (see EDIT at the bottom)

Unfortunately if you click on the solution you can see i added an `<text>This is a text without id</text>` to the source.

Is there a possibility that this also gets rendered just without the `div` around it?

Comment: @CrazyEight, consider to raise that as a new, different question, with minimal but complete samples in the question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I found my final solution now anyway :) See EDIT EDIT